# How to include closing note in column view?

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to configure org-mode column view to display the [closing note](https://orgmode.org/manual/Closing-items.html) of TODO entries so that I can see why they are closed easily. I read the manual but did not find a way.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

When you have something like `(setq org-log-done 'note)` in your configuration, a closing note is inserted as follows when your turn the entry state to DONE:

```
* DONE my task
  CLOSED: [2023-02-21 Tue 01:11]
  :LOGBOOK:
  - CLOSING NOTE [2023-02-21 Tue 01:11] \\
    my closing note
  :END:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the closing notes in column view using the approach of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75436/33424), you just need to change the regexp used. The following will put the first line of each closing note in column view provided "CNOTE" is part of the [columns definition](https://orgmode.org/manual/Scope-of-column-definitions.html):

```lisp
(defun my-column-display-value-transformer (column-title value)
  "Modifies the value to display in column view."
  (when (and (equal column-title "CNOTE")
             (org-back-to-heading)
             (re-search-forward
              "^- CLOSING NOTE \\[.*\\] \\\\\\\\\\\n +\\(.*\\) *$"
              (org-entry-end-position) t))
    (match-string-no-properties 1)))

(setq org-columns-modify-value-for-display-function
      #'my-column-display-value-transformer)
```